# The touchstart and touchend event listeners are not removed

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, touch

I'm trying to make a swipe-close function. When the user swipes in a certain way, the div has its class removed. It works, but not completely. When I load a page wider than 1024px, the swipe gesture doesn't work (as expected). When I load a page that is less or equal to 1024px, the swipe gesture works (as expected). However, when I load a page that's less or equal to 1024px and then resize the window to be wider than 1024px, the swipe still works (but shouldn't). I don't think that the `document.removeEventListener("touchstart", handleTouchStart);`
and
`document.removeEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd);`
at the end of the code are actually removing the event listener. How to fix that?

```
    function swipeClose(){  

            // Set these variables (all relative to innerWidth / innerHeight)

        // Min horizontal swipe distance 
        let minSwipeWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.45;

        // Max vertical swipe distance  
        let maxSwipeHeight = window.innerHeight * 0.15;

        // Min start point from the edge
        let swipeStartPoint = window.innerWidth * 0.05;

        // Max start point from the edge
        let swipeEndPoint = window.innerWidth * 0.35;

        // Set the swipe min and max start point from the right edge
        const swipeRightStartPoint = window.innerWidth - swipeStartPoint;
        const swipeRightEndPoint = window.innerWidth - swipeEndPoint;

            // Track touch start and end coordinates

        let touchStartX = null;
        let touchEndX = null;

        function handleTouchStart(e){
            touchStartX = e.touches[0].clientX;
            touchStartY = e.touches[0].clientY;
        }

            // Check the conditions and perform the action

        function handleTouchEnd(e){

            // Calculate the swipe X and Y lengths
            touchEndX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
            touchEndY = e.changedTouches[0].clientY;
            let swipeWidth = Math.abs(touchEndX - touchStartX);
            let swipeHeight = Math.abs(touchEndY - touchStartY);

            // check the requirements
            if (swipeWidth >= minSwipeWidth &&
                swipeHeight <= maxSwipeHeight){

                if (touchStartX >= swipeStartPoint && 
                touchStartX <= swipeEndPoint ||
                touchStartX <= swipeRightStartPoint && 
                touchStartX >= swipeRightEndPoint){

                    scContainer.removeClass(scOpen);

                }
            }

            // Reset touch start and end coordinates
            touchStartX = null;
            touchEndX = null;
        }

        // Listen for the swipe (if the window is <= 1024 px wide)
        if (window.innerWidth <= 1024) {
            document.addEventListener("touchstart", handleTouchStart);
            document.addEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd);
        } else {
            document.removeEventListener("touchstart", handleTouchStart);
            document.removeEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd);
        }
    }

    // Call the function on load and window resize
    swipeClose();
    window.addEventListener("resize", swipeClose);
```

Comment: try with `pointerup` event.

Comment: @NinaScholz It didn't help. Shouldn't touch events work?

Comment: maybe with the other event, `pointerdown`.

Comment: I've already tried it. Even if it worked (it didn't), I want to use the touch events.